# Validation phonenumbers column python pandas with phonenumbers library

Tags: python, pandas, libphonenumber

I want to check multiple phone numbers from my dataframe with phonenumbers library
https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/

I want to validate the phone numbers and eventually i want to know from which country the number is. So for example:

| contact | phoneNumber | phoneCheck | phoneCountry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31650868016 | True | Netherlands |
| 2 | 447986123456 | True | United Kingdom |
| 3 | 55677 | False |  |

I used this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782746 I made a Country column.

But I want to use phonenumbers.is_valid_number() function and eventually the geocoder.description_for_number() function.

```
df['phone_number_clean'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
                              phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.is_valid_number(str(x.phoneNumber), 
                                                 str(x.Country)), 
                              axis='columns'))
```

Error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'phoneNumber'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific issue causing this error is a misplaced parantheses after `axis` instead of before:

```
df['phone_number_clean'] = df.apply(lambda x: phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.is_valid_number(str(x.phoneNumber), str(x.phoneCountry))), axis='columns')
```

I think below is more what you're looking for though:

```
df['phone_number_clean'] = df.apply(lambda x: phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phonenumbers.parse("+"+str(x.phoneNumber), None)), axis=1)
```

I used None as a placeholder because you didn't have country code in your DataFrame.